# A book about two pigs that get invited to a dinner by a wolf and then it tries to kill them, then the wolf gets cooked in a pie

Tags: identification-request

The front cover has the two pigs, and a haunted looking house with the wolf in the window. It’s been years and I just remembered this children's book.

Comment: Welcome to Literature Stack Exchange, take our [tour]! Please read the [identification-request wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) and, if any of the prompts there jog your memory, please [edit] further information into your question. For example, approximately when did you read this book? (We don't know when you were a child). What age range would it have been aimed at? Was it illustrated, and if so, what style were the illustrations in? How large was it (both thickness and cover area)?

Answer (score 3):

*The Mystery of Eatum Hall* by John Kelly and Cathy Tincknell looks like a possibility, though the cover is different and it's a goose and a hog couple instead of two pigs. Description copied from [goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/849464.The_Mystery_of_Eatum_Hall):

> Glenda and Horace Pork-Fowler are a goose and a hog of large
> proportions, with appetites to match. So naturally, when they receive
> an invitation for a weekend of free gourmet food at Eatum Hall, Dr.
> Hunter's new inn, they don't hesitate to pack their bags. It's a bit
> curious that there's no one to greet them at the gloomy inn, and their
> absent owner does have an odd fondness for artwork depicting wolves.
> Still, the unfailingly cheerful couple are more than content to eat
> their way from feast to feast, disappointed only to learn that they'll
> miss the pie-eating festival on the day they leave. Or will they?
>
> With graphic artwork that pops off the page, this tongue-in-cheek tale
> will delight readers of all ages, from fans of Wallace and Gromit and
> Berkeley Breathed to children who will love discovering the
> illustrator's many sight gags — and being in on the joke.